# Missing Links and Field Maps

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I created a document to represent what I see with my config file to show differences. Some of the items may not be resolved, but anything you can do to help would be greatly appreciated.

- Not picking up all the user stories but have selected to get all
  Missing links
- Missing Epics (doing some research, it seems that the Epic Was migrated unparented; it is probably related to the issue with missing links, which is happening for almost all items
- Bugs have different fields (Description and Acceptance Criteria not migrated or not showing up)
- Description merging with Acceptance Criteria
- Attachments not coming and tried everything to have them come over even if when they are way under the limit
- History of comments not migrated
- Status not migrated
- Tests not associated with User Stories
- Some test cases were not migrated
- Load Tests were not migrated
- Test Runs not migrated

Migrated from: https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/issues/632

Answer (score 0):

Yes, start with a fresh copy and see what falls out.

You can remove the old ones using:

```
    {
      "ObjectType": "WorkItemDeleteConfig",
      "Enabled": false,
      "QueryBit": "AND [System.WorkItemType] NOT IN ('Test Suite', 'Test Plan')",
      "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc"
    },
```

> Missing Epics (doing some research, it seems that the Epic Was migrated unparented; it is probably related to the issue with missing links, which is happening for almost all items

There was a bug with links that have now been resolved, but it seems that you need to migrate those items again.

> Bugs have different fields (Description and Acceptance Criteria not migrated or not showing up)

If you have different fields on the source and target then you need to add a custom set of field maps.

> Description merging with Acceptance Criteria

Do you have a field map that merges them?

```
    {
      "ObjectType": "FieldMergeMapConfig",
      "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
      "sourceField1": "System.Description",
      "sourceField2": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
      "targetField": "System.Description",
      "formatExpression": "{0} <br/><br/><h3>Acceptance Criteria</h3>{1}",
      "doneMatch": "##DONE##"
    },
```

This is the example field map that is added to the template config.

> Attachments not coming and tried everything to have them come over even if when they are way under the limit
> History of comments not migrated
> Status not migrated
> Tests not associated with User Stories

This is likely related to the previous issue and clearing the items should resolve it.

> Some test cases were not migrated

Only things within scope for the WIQLQueryBit are migrated. I would check the scope and see if they are excluded. Test Cases are just Work Items.

> Load Tests were not migrated

There is no way to migrate load tests, you will have to do these manually.

> Test Runs not migrated

There is no way to migrate Test Runs.